# How can I add dependancy files in Debian Package in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I am trying build a debian package with some dependencies... Let me know how can I add dependencies into it. I have tried putting it in control file... but it is not working.. i am following this link:
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html

Answer (score 1):

In your `debian/control` file you need a line that looks similar to this:

`Depends: foo, bar, baz(>=1.0)`

Edit: `dpkg -i` does not download dependencies only apt-get does that. You normally need to run `sudo apt-get install -f` after you used `dpkg -i` unless you add your package to an apt repository and install it from there